# Setting a column width on multiple columns in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Jeeped and CLR kindly provided the code that added a variable number of columns to a worksheet named *sht02AnalysisSummary* starting at Column D whilst copying the borders and formulae of Column C.

```
AddCol = txtNrEvaluated

With sht02AnalysisSummary
    Set rangeCopy = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    rangeCopy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rangeCopy.Rows.Count, AddCol)
End With
```

This code, however, does not copy the format of Column C in terms of width and although I have experimented with `EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15` with the `With End With` and even its own `With End With`, I have been unsuccessful.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Column Widths are only copied across when you are copying across entire columns and nor ranges :) `rng.ColumnWidth = 15` should work

Comment: more specifically to your case ... this should work `.Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rangeCopy.Rows.Count, AddCol).ColumnWidth = 15`

Comment: I did try ColumnWdth = 15 at the beginning but it adjusted the column widths on the page that the AddCol information was being read from.  I don't know why, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment below your question.

Column Widths are only copied across when you are copying across entire columns and nor ranges. Also `rng.ColumnWidth = 15` should work

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim rangeCopy As Range, destRng As Range

AddCol = 2

With sht02AnalysisSummary
    Set rangeCopy = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    Set destRng = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rangeCopy.Rows.Count, AddCol)
    rangeCopy.Copy destRng
    destRng.ColumnWidth = 15
End With
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It's giving me an Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.  I'm using Excel 2010 but cannot see why this would be a reason.

Comment: I tested the code before posting :). I assumed that `AddCol = 1`

Comment: It's variable.  It's normally in the range of 2 to 7 but could reach as high as 20

Comment: Tried with those values as well. it is till working for me. One moment updating screenshots in the answer above

Comment: Ah, no. I spotted a typo in my spreadsheet. Let me try again.

Comment: BTW do you want o manually set the column or do what @CLR suggested?  `rangePaste.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = rangeCopy.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth`?

Comment: No, I'm happy with your solution to determine that the ColumnWidth is 15.  The worksheet page has to handle totals no more than £99m (to 2 decimal places) so a width of 15 is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the source tab's column C width across to the new columns, you could use:

```
Dim rangeCopy As Range, rangePaste As Range
Dim Addcol As Integer

Addcol = NrEvaluated

With sht02AnalysisSummary

    Set rangeCopy = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    Set rangePaste = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(rangeCopy.Rows.Count, Addcol)

    rangeCopy.Copy Destination:=rangePaste
    rangePaste.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = rangeCopy.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth

End With
```

Comment: Ah, I tried setting up a rangePaste but never worked out the last line.  I'll remember that one too.  Many thanks.